# Where can I ask suggestions for a stock tracking app?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-topics

As per title, I'm looking for an iOS app that can track a set (technical name is portfolio?) of stocks:

- give me the value of each stock in real time (this is something even the barebones [Stocks](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/stocks/id1069512882) app does)
- alert me if the price of a certain stock exceeds certain upper/lower bounds defined by me

That's all. I don't want to buy/trade anything. Just get price alerts. However, according to

https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

I see that such a question would be off-topic here:

> - Use of software for managing one's finances. (**Not recommendations**, just questions regarding specific software)

Where can I ask such a question in the SE hierarchy?

Comment: Here’s the OP’s new question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/82788/83

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general there's no guarantee there's anywhere in the SE network where a particular question would be on-topic. However in this case https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is reasonably likely. (But you should check its on-topic list for yourself.)

Comment: You're right: my question was a shorthand for "can I ask my Q on the SE network, and if yes, where?". I may have been not clear enough.

Comment: Given that you actually asked on meta first, I thought you probably did realise it; but it's something I end up saying to people asking off-topic questions every so often so it felt worth saying for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: +1, this is on-topic at SoftwareRecs.SE. They even have a [finance tag](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance).